# How to append list entries to a JSON file through a for loop?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

In the following code, I am trying to append every oth element to a JSON file:

```
title = []  # api_result['search_results']['title']
asin = []  # api_result['search_results']['asin']
link = []  # api_result['search_results']['link']
categories = []  # api_result['search_results']['categories'][0]['name']
image_url = []  # api_result['search_results']['image']
rating = []
rating_total = []
price = []  # apit_result['prices'][0]['value']
top_positive_review = []
top_positive_review_rating = []
top_critical_review = []
top_critical_review_rating = []
ratings_total_filtered = []  # apit_result['']
reviews_total_filtered = []
reviews_total = []
reviews = []

for o in range(len(title)):
    with open("metadata.jsonl", "w+") as outfile:
        entry = {
                'title': title[o],
                'asin': asin[o],
                'link': link[o],
                'categories': categories[o],
                'image_url': image_url[o],
                'rating': rating[o],
                'rating_total': rating_total[o],
                'price': price[o],
                'top_positive_review': top_positive_review[o],
                'top_positive_review_rating': top_positive_review_rating[o],
                'top_critical_review': top_critical_review[o],
                'top_critical_review_rating': top_critical_review_rating[o],
                'ratings_total_filtered': ratings_total_filtered[o],
                'reviews_total_filtered': reviews_total_filtered[o],
                'reviews_total': reviews_total[o],
                'reviews': reviews[o]}
```

I take that this isn't the proper way of doing this. Basically, I want entries like this in the `metadata.jsonl` file:

```
{"title":"some title", "asin":"ABCDEF", ...}
{"title":"another title", "asin":"GHIJKL", ...}
...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: " I am trying to append every oth element to a JSON file:" Every oth element **of what**? And if you want `o` to mean the distance between elements in a list (**I think**?), then it cannot also mean the numeric values that you get from the `range`. Please read [ask] and [mre] and try to show a **simple but complete** example: what might be in `title`? What might be the value of `o`? Exactly what should the corresponding result be?

Comment: Every oth element of the lists

Comment: To be clear: you mean that `o` should be an integer that is defined ahead of time, such as `3`; and that would mean that element 0, element 3, element 6 etc. should get used?

Comment: People usually do `for i in range`. I just swapped i with o because its my initial. That;'s it.

Comment: Okay, so you want every element? Or just what? Please actually **explain a concrete problem**. What happens when you try your existing code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the file must be done only once with the `with open` block, otherwise it opens and closes the file at each iteration.

Thereafter, just wrap at each iteration.

Look at this code:

```py
import json

# I am assuming your data in this form
title = ['title_0', 'title_1']
link = ['link_0', 'link_1']

with open("metadata.jsonl", "w") as file:
    for o in range(len(title)):
        entry = {
            'title': title[o],
            'link': link[o],
        }
        json_object = json.dumps(entry, ensure_ascii=False)  # on line json
        file.write(json_object)
        file.write("\n")
```

output will be:

```
{"title": "title_0", "link": "link_0"}
{"title": "title_1", "link": "link_1"}
```

Comment: This works, but what if I try to fetch `title` key. Won't it just return the first one?

Comment: The jsonl was born for other purposes (such as processing an http request by sending one line at a time). Look at its [manifest](https://jsonlines.org/) to clarify your ideas.

Comment: Then the `json` data would be of no use. Since, you won't be able to fetch specific values.